# How much do the V-22 Osprey's wings weigh?

Tags: wing, v-22

I am trying to ascertain the weight of the V-22's entire wing assembly: right, left and center including both nacelles. But excluding the engines if possible.

Comment: There is a method for deriving structural wing weight from geometric data in Appendix C, [Synthesis of Subsonic Airplane Design by E. Torenbeek](https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A229f2817-9be9-49b6-959a-d653b5bac054)